# How to get the database vendor name from Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using spring Jdbc , How do i retrieve the database vendor name from the jdbc template without going via the Connection interface . Is there an API provided by Spring which could give an enum holding the DB name so that i can decouple my code from hardcoding a string value

Answer (score 7):

You could find the information you need into [DatabaseMetaData documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html).

```
String vendor = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
```

UPDATED!

As recommended by M. Deinum, you could use a ConnectionCallback so you won't need to close the connection or take care of it.

For example:

```
private String getProduct() {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.execute(new ConnectionCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public String doInConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException,
            DataAccessException {

            return connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is actually dangerous, as you are opening an unmanaged connection. Instead you should use a `ConnectionCallback` or close the connection again.

Comment: Well, this is an example of how to find the information he wants. Of course the connection has to be well managed, but that is not the question here. The question is where to find this, and I don't think you can get this information without using a Connection.

Comment: I'm not saying that. But in my experience people copy/paste code from here and then after x times calling this code run into issues due to a depleted pool. Hence mu suggestion of using a `ConnectionCallback` in which you don't need to close it (or think on closing it).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didnt think about people copying and pasting code :) I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you , i am already using this . The issue is i would need to know the  vendor name upfront for a given database , without using the above code to find it . Is there anyway i can get an enum for DB , something like this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/Database.html , so that am not dependent on the string value

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this to obtain an underlying connection and then release it once you get information you need from database metadata.

```
DataSource dataSource = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
String dbProductName = connection.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(connection, dataSource);
```

Hope this helps you. !

Comment: Thank you , i am already using this . The issue is i would need to know the  vendor name upfront for a given database , without using the above code to find it . Is there anyway i can get an enum for DB , something like this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/Database.html , so that am not dependent on the string value

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use `JdbcUtils#extractDatabaseMetaData` method - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcUtils.html#extractDatabaseMetaData-javax.sql.DataSource-java.lang.String-

Like:

`JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource(), "getDatabaseProductName");`

There is also a `JdbcUtils#commonDatabaseName` method that attempts to normalize the database product names - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcUtils.html#commonDatabaseName-java.lang.String-

Comment: So the usage should be like the following ? JdbcUtils.commonDatabaseName(JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource(), "getDatabaseProductName"))

Comment: Sure, that looks good to me, if you want to combine them, although you need to cast the argument to `commonDatabaseName` as a `String`.